# How to get sender position at MAC layer

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am working with Veins 4.7.1 to develop a trust model. For that purpose, I need to access the position of the message sender in x and y coordinates at the lower layer. I know, we have a specific field to access sender position in 'WaveShortMessage' messages, which can provide sender location at the application layer. Also, there is no field for sender position in 'Mac80211Pkt'.

I have gone through the related questions in stack overflow, but I am unable to find anything related to my question.  Can anyone guide me in this direction?

Comment: In OMNeT++, you can add new fields to messages by editing the .msg file. Simply add the fields you need, fill them in the sending vehicle, then read them at the receiver. If you want to simulate how this new field causes the message length to increase, make sure to set the message length to a higher value at the sender.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.